# SDK version for building swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, github, build

I am trying to build swift from the source (https://github.com/apple/swift). However, it throws an error when building PhaseScriptExecution. Here is the error message:

```
<unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.11.sdk'
make: *** [/Users/yangwei/Git/build/Xcode-DebugAssert/swift-macosx-x86_64/stdlib/public/core/macosx/x86_64/Swift.o] Error 1

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution CMake\ Rules /Users/yangwei/Git/build/Xcode-DebugAssert/swift-macosx-x86_64/stdlib/public/core/Swift.build/Debug/add_custom_command_target-8e6e230f23a92c1cda79a3cf59140ab8-Swift.o.build/Script-4123DECAA170465EA6F4D9CC.sh
(1 failure)
```

It seems to be a problem related to SDK version. Can anyone tell me which SDK version I should use? and how can I downgrade to the version?

Thanks!

Update:

I noticed the version issue so I tried to checkout branch of swift-2.2 of swift and all other required projects. However, when I tried to build with command `utils/build-script -x`, it shows following error message:

```
make -f /Users/yangwei/Git/build/Xcode-DebugAssert/llvm-macosx-x86_64/CMakeScripts/ReRunCMake.make
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/Users/yangwei/Git/llvm/lib/DebugInfo/CodeView/CMakeLists.txt', needed by '/Users/yangwei/Git/build/Xcode-DebugAssert/llvm-macosx-x86_64/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache'.  Stop.
make: *** [/Users/yangwei/Git/build/Xcode-DebugAssert/llvm-macosx-x86_64/CMakeFiles/ZERO_CHECK] Error 2
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution CMake\ Rules /Users/yangwei/Git/build/Xcode-DebugAssert/llvm-macosx-x86_64/LLVM.build/Debug/ZERO_CHECK.build/Script-80DAA73EAB654B0EA77D1AEF.sh
(1 failure)
utils/build-script: command terminated with a non-zero exit status 65, aborting
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the new XCode 8 beta to build the latest Swift source.

Once installed, try:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Comment: I noticed the version issue so I tried to checkout branch of swift-2.2 of swift and all other required projects. However, when I tried to build with command `utils/build-script -x`, it shows following error message: `
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/Users/yangwei/Git/llvm/lib/DebugInfo/CodeView/CMakeLists.txt', needed by '/Users/yangwei/Git/build/Xcode-DebugAssert/llvm-macosx-x86_64/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache'.  Stop.
make: *** [/Users/yangwei/Git/build/Xcode-DebugAssert/llvm-macosx-x86_64/CMakeFiles/ZERO_CHECK] Error 2
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
** BUILD FAILED **
`

Comment: Try removing the `build` directory.